# target link within div jquery

Tags: jquery

say i have

```
<div class="mydiv">

<a href="#" name="mylink">sfds</a>

</div>
```

How would i target the A link with jQuery?

```
$(".mydiv a[name]").tooltip();
```

I've tried the above but it doesn't seem to select it correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Using `a[name]` will return to you a collection of all anchors with a name attribute.

By the looks of it you only want to make reference to an anchor with a specific value in the name attribute.

To do this you need to make reference to the name you're looking for.

```
.mydiv a[name=myink]
```

You can learn more about the CSS Attribute Selectors here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors

**UPDATE**

The issue you're having seems to be with the name attribute.

Using the title attribute instead seems to work fine.

Quick example http://jsfiddle.net/n6agg/

Comment: Im trying to use the 'name' attribute as my tooltip, as shown here http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html

Comment: Updated my answer Jim. I hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('.mydiv a[name="mylink"]').tooltip();
```

Comment: Im trying to use the 'name' attribute as my tooltip, as shown here http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html